# Server runs out of memory - how to diagnose (vim error_log?)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

We are hosting possibly hundreds of hosting accounts on our dedicated hosting, however they are very niche and most of them are development accounts, unused or low traffic websites.

However we have infrequent crashes, caused by lack of memory (our web hosts tell us). I'm no expert on servers and stuff, but a `ps aux` turns up this line:

```
root     11905 95.5 55.0 1151616 1135256 pts/0 R+   09:05  40:38 vim error_log
```

Now I'm no expert, but 95.5% cpu and 55% ram usage seems pretty high for an error log. Is this right?

Could it be this that is causing the out of memory errors?

I've tried to add the rest of the `ps aux` output, but it doesn't format very nicely. I can take a screenshot if you think that it would be useful.

Otherwise, we're running a pretty standard server set up I think. Ubuntu, 2gb ram. I don't think that hdd space is running low, I assume our host would pick up on that (`df` says "no file systems processed"). A lot of our websites are Wordpress websites, I've heard that this can cause problems, but they're not high traffic at all.

It could be a rogue plugin we have used in a Wordpress installation somewhere, but how would I pinpoint that? (We had this problem a while back and it seemed to be a guessing game until we found a plugin on one of our sites that was reading and writing to a db table with 250,000 rows - and increasing). Deleting this plugin made the server work again, no more crashes, till last night when we got the dreaded out of memory error again.

Any pointers would be good, thanks.

Comment: How large is your error_log? And why in the world is anybody trying to edit it with `vim`?

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought that `vim error_log` was a background process that was running (i.e. vim was creating an error log or something), but actually it is a command that someone has run right? I haven't accessed error logs for a very long time (and I normally use cat, although may have used vim in the past - bit of a linux newbie!). Apache error_log was about 18gb(!) (again, newbie on that too, I'm just a programmer really!) so I've deleted that, killed the vim process and hopefully that should help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vim is opening a ginourmos file. Stop doing that, use tools like `tail`, `less`, `grep` to read only the parts you need.